# Spring Web Flow Model Validation won't work properly

Tags: java, spring, jsp, validation, spring-webflow

I am currently working on a web application, which uses Spring Web Flow for some forms. I want to use the automatic validation powered by spring, so therefore I have

- instantiated a 'validator' bean in my spring web flow configuration file (Class LocalValidatorFactoryBean).
- Created a method with the signature validate{VieStateId}(ValidationContext context) inside my model (which is associated to the view state in the flow configuration as a model).
- Used spring:bind tag from the spring tag library to show error message if it appears.

So far my web flow view page won't go further when Validator is associated, so I can see that it is going to my validate method. The problem is that I can't get my error message to show. When testing ${status.error} inside my bind tag, then it returns false, always.

My Validate method inside my Model Class.

```
public void validateEnterMovieDetails(ValidationContext context) {
    if (context.getUserEvent().equals("next")) {
        MessageContext messages = context.getMessageContext();

        if (this.title.isEmpty() || this.title == null) {
            messages.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().source("title").code("validation.movie.title.required").build())
        }
    }
}
```

My JSP file

```
<form:form modelAttribute="movie" action="${flowExecutionUrl}">
    <spring:bind path="title">
        <c:if test="${status.error}">
            <form:errors path="title" />
        </c:if>
    </spring:bind>
</form:form>
```

My problem is that it seems that my validation is working, since when I apply this validate method, then I can't go to the next view in the flow, though My bind can't seem to find any errors at all.

So I hope anyone please can help me solve this problem, since I have tried search the web for answers, and nothing seemed to help. You can see the full source code to my project at my GitHub account - https://github.com/martin-rohwedder/movstream

Comment: Just in case there's some mis-match between the path the errors are being registered against and what the form:errors tag is asking for, try specifying `<form:errors path="*" />` which will pump out any errors associated with any fields (but may help to give an idea to where the problem is).

Comment: When I am using * it aint showing any error text. I have tried to use the new MessageBuilder().error().source("title").defaultText("There was an error").build(), which aint working either

Comment: What is that test of `${status.error}` referencing? Where does that variable get set?

Answer (score 0):

Is 'EnterMovieDetails' really the id of one of your view? (if you could post you WebFlow config file, that'd be helpful).

If you use SWF 2, please have a look at the paragraph 4.10 of [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/pdf/spring-webflow-reference.pdf).

You first need to make sure that your validation method contains the view id in its name.

Also, I don't think you need to use a bind tag in your JSP around your error tag.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, sorry EnterMovieDetails is not the ID, it was mistake I wrote in the hurry. The real ID is 'createmovie1'. The web flow Config file for the create movie flow can be seen here - https://github.com/martin-rohwedder/movstream/blob/master/src/main/webapp/views/flows/admin/movie/new/new-flow.xml